# How to Encrypt Files For Modelsim with Vivado

Tags: encryption, vhdl, vivado

A vendor is using a tool which compiles some code into raw VHDL. They do not wish for me to see the raw code and instead want to encrypt the output files. At the moment they encrypt it into EDIF netlists using Vivado.

This is fine when implementing the design; I take it as a black box, use the wrapper for the i/o and write the bitstream. They ensure me their black box design works. I indeed see my resource usage going up to what I expect however I would like to simulate and verify their results.

When trying to simulate it with modelsim, it of course has no idea how to decrypt these files. If you write the netlists to VHDL, you just get the error:

```
# ** Error: Formatter.vhd(58329): near "AES128-CBC": Unknown session key in protected region
```

I asked them to include the encryption key for modelsim when encrypting these files, but they did not know how to.

I understand their rough workflow with their .tcl is:

```
synth_design -top Formatter
write_edif -force ./Formatteredf
```

So my question is, how do they include the modelsim encryption key when they generate the EDIF files with Vivado?

Answer (score 1):

Modelsim cannot simulate EDIF.  You need to convert the EDIF to a format that can be simulated.  You mention Vivado, so you would use `write_verilog` or `write_vhdl` to convert these.

I don't have access to any encrypted 3rd party netlists, but I did use some encrypted Xilinx IP (specifically the ila_v6).  After synthesizing, I opened the synthesized results and did the following:

```
write_vhdl -mode funcsim -cell test_ila/U0 ila_funcsim.vhd
```

Now, `test_ila` is the instance I created at the top level, and `U0` is the encrypted instance inside.  The generated VHDL was just a netlist of UNISIM primitives.  And it happily compiled under Modelsim.  There was no encrypted IP in the netlist.

So, I presume you have something like this:

```
component encrypted_ip is
...
end component encrypted_ip;
```

Then you add the encrypted EDIF, which is treated as a blackbox, but eventually pulled into the synthesis/implementation.  So, open either the synthesized or implemented design, and use `write_vhdl` to dump the component to a netlist.

Comment: Yeah but that still doesn't answer the question. write_vhdl still holds the encryption for vivado and not modelsim. How do you include the encryption key for modelsim?

Comment: @fiz I've updated the answer with some testing I did with some Vivado encrypted IP.

Answer (score 1):

If the EDIF is encrypted, write_vhdl will almost certainly produce another encrypted netlist. That VHDL netlist might simulate in Modelsim, but I would guess not.

Modelsim comes with a tool "vhencrypt.exe" which will encrypt the source using IEEE 1735. The resulting file can be simulated by Modelsim, but you have to start with the source, not the EDIF. You would now have the problem of using the EDIF in Vivado and the vhencrypt output in Modelsim, but it's a step in the right direction.

IEEE 1735 can produce a single output that can be consumed by both Vivado and Modelsim, but you will need to provide a public key from Xilinx. As far as I know, Xilinx does not publish their public key for 1735, but they would probably share it with an IP partner.